# What is the correct way to work with an object that was stored in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, reference

Coming from Java, I am confused about how to correctly access an object that was stored in a vector.

In this test case, I expected both outputs to display the same number (2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Item {
public:
  int id = 0;
  Item(int id)
  {
    this->id = id;
  }
};

int main()
{
  vector<Item> items;
  Item item = Item(1);
  items.push_back(item);

  Item itemFromVector = items.at(0);
  itemFromVector.id = 2;

  cout << "item: " << item.id << endl;
  cout << "itemFromVector: " <<  itemFromVector.id << endl;
}
// output:
// item: 1
// itemFromVector: 2
```

Comment: You don't need vectors to observe this phenomenon.  `Item item = Item(1); Item item2 = item; item2.id = 2; cout << item.id << endl;`.

Comment: In your test case, `item` is an object, `itemFromVector` is another, separate object, and the vector stores yet another object, distinct from the two above. Each one has ita own copy of the data.

Comment: Alrighty, but how do you do this then in c++? Should I not use vector?

Comment: Btw, `Item item = Item(1);` is a redundant javaism. `Item item(1);` will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you will have `item.id` equal to 1.

The reason behind this is the `push_back` call will execute a COPY of your object in the vector (The `Item` in your vector and `item` are 2 different objects).

One way to observe what you are trying to achieve is to use pointer:

```
int main()
{
  vector<Item*> items; //items contains addresses of Item object
  Item item = Item(1);
  items.push_back(&item); // push address of your item

  Item* itemFromVector = items.at(0); // Pointer to item
  itemFromVector->id = 2; // Modify item id attribute

  cout << "item: " << item.id << endl; // Access item id attribute
  cout << "itemFromVector: " <<  itemFromVector->id << endl; // Access item id attribute
}
```

Comment: ok, currently processing this... looks like pointers behave more like what I am used to from references in Java...

Comment: @Zalumon Just added some comments to help

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. In that case, I will work with pointers. Thank you all very much for your help. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer. I think Jérôme was first with the pointer solution. I upvoted all answers, though.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute:

```
items.push_back(item);
```

a copy of `item` is stored in the vector. The two objects, `item` and the copy in the vector, are completely separate objects. Changes to one does not affect the other.

If you want to be able to change one and expect the change reflected in the other, you'll need to create a vector of pointers or a vector of [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class Item {
   public:
      int id = 0;
      Item(int id)
      {
         this->id = id;
      }
};

void test1()
{
   std::cout << "Output from test1() ...\n";
   std::vector<Item*> items;
   Item item(1);
   items.push_back(&item);

   Item* itemFromVector = items.at(0);
   itemFromVector->id = 2;

   std::cout << "item: " << item.id << std::endl;
   std::cout << "itemFromVector: " <<  itemFromVector->id << std::endl;
}

void test2()
{
   std::cout << "Output from test1() ...\n";
   std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Item>> items;
   Item item(1);
   items.push_back(item);

   Item& itemFromVector = items.at(0);
   itemFromVector.id = 20;

   std::cout << "item: " << item.id << std::endl;
   std::cout << "itemFromVector: " <<  itemFromVector.id << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   test1();
   test2();
}
```

Output:

```
Output from test1() ...
item: 2
itemFromVector: 2
Output from test1() ...
item: 20
itemFromVector: 20
```

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, thanks for pointing out the error. I needed to overhaul the answer :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: What? It takes the argument either by `T const&` or by `T&&`, doesn't it?

Comment: @ChristianHackl, That comment was before I overhauled my answer.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Actually you're right.  But the effect is the same; `vector` will make a copy of the argument to be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<Item> items;
```

In this code you have a list of Item class.
When you call `items.push_back(item);` you push a copy of `item` in `items` array. so when you call `itemFromVector.id = 2;` you change the id of the copy that you just put in the array.

If you want to copy the original `item` object into array and make edits afterwards you have to do the following changes:

```
vector<Item*> items;
items.push_back(&item);
Item* itemFromVector = items.at(0);
itemFromVector->id = 2;
```

In the first line you tell the vector that we want to store pointer of `Item` class instead of a copy of it.
In the second line we push the address of `item` into our array by adding `&` before our variable name.
In the third line we tell the compiler that our variable type as a pointer of `Item` class by adding `*` before our variable name.
And in the forth line we change `.` to `->` since we are working with a pointer object.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are coming from Java, it will not be difficult for you to use *references* in C++ in order to obtain the expected behavior.

> Item item = Item(1);

Unlike in Java, item here is not a reference, but an actual instance. You could construct it immediately without the assignment:

```
Item item(1);
```

> items.push_back(item);

Here you need to know that what you pushed in the vector in NOT a reference to item, but a copy of it, a real new instance that copies from item.

> Item itemFromVector = items.at(0);

Here you exected itemFromVector to be a *reference* to the first item in the vector. But actually it is an instance copied from it. If you want a reference, declare it as reference, it is that simple:

```
Item& itemFromVector = items.at(0);
```

In summary, when working with Java, *everything is a reference*. This is not true in C++. A reference is a reference only if it is *explicitly* declared as a reference.

Comment: It's more like Java does not have C++-style references, and what Java calls "references" (except in `NullPointerException`) would be pointers in C++. And it's not true that *everything* in Java is a reference (or pointer), because primitives are not.

Comment: @ChristianHackl *everything is a reference* is just an adage and should not be taken literally. It applies to variables defined to manipulate objects, as you cannot instantiate an object "directly" (on the stack actually) without using new. Well, again, just an adage used to explain this major difference from C++. :)

Comment: What may add to the confusion is that in C++ terminology, "object" has a much wider meaning and encompasses instances of primitive types.

Comment: @ChristianHackl in C++ ? or rather in Java?

Comment: In C++. In a line like `int x = 0;`, it would be correct to talk about "the int object".

Comment: True, and moreover in C++ you can define pointers and references on primitive types. In Java you need to wrao them explicitly in objects such as Integer, Double etc. Too many confusion between Java and C++. I wonder if it is a wise decision to teach Java before C++. The move from C++ to Java looks much easier than in the other way.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   Item(int id)
>   {
>     this->id = id;
>   }
> ```

That's a typical Java-ism. The idiomatical C++ way is:

```
Item(int id) : id(id) {}
```

> ```
> Item item = Item(1);
> ```

This, too. The idiomatical C++ way is:

```
Item item(1);
```

> ```
> items.push_back(item);
> ```

This creates a **copy** of `item` and stores the copy in the vector.

> ```
> Item itemFromVector = items.at(0);
> ```

Likewise, this creates a **copy** of the first item and stores it in the `itemFromVector` variable.

You may think of Java code such as:

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
list.add(item);
Item item = list.get(0);
```

But that's the **wrong analogy**. Java just stores pointers in the list. A more suitable Java analogy would be:

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
list.add(item.clone());
Item item = list.get(0).clone();
```

If you want C++ to exhibit the behaviour of a Java `list.add(item); Item item = list.get(0);`, then you would have to create a vector of pointers:

```
  vector<Item*> items;
  Item item(1);
  items.push_back(&item);

  Item* itemFromVector = items.at(0);
  itemFromVector->id = 2;
```

But C++ is not Java, so this is not a common thing to do and results in various problems related to the fact that C++ does not have any built-in garbage collection. As a general guideline, avoid pointers if you can, and be especially careful with pointers to local objects.

Comment: Okidoki, thank you for the explanation in java, which makes it crystal clear to me ;-). But now I feel like I am back at square one. If you do not encourage this solution, what do you propose then?

Comment: @Zalumon: You are welcome :) But what solution are you looking for? What's the *problem*, really?

Comment: I mean, how do c++ programmers typically work with lists of objects, if the pointer approach you and the others outlined is discouraged?

Comment: @Zalumon: The recommended approach is to just work with a vector of `T` and not of `T*` until you run into particular problems and need something more complex. My example is a particularly dangerous one because I took a pointer to a local object, which can lead to problems when the local object is destroyed but the pointer to it is still hanging around somewhere else. May I ask what makes the pointer approach so attractive in your opinion?

Comment: nothing in particular. I'm just trying to figure out how to work with a list of objects in c++. And since my first Java-like approach immediately produced unexpected behavior (to me), I came here looking for the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Zalumon: I think you should try to learn more about pointers, references and dynamic memory allocation with single objects. With containers and everything, it's probably harder to understand. (On the other hand, to be honest, I am not sure how I'd teach C++ these days. Low-level basics first or useful abstractions first?) Anyway, if there's one thing which Java programmers keep getting wrong in C++, then it's their overuse of pointers and `new`.